# Can you run Timer and .onTapGesture together? (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui

I am new to swift, and I was trying to set a game timer for a game, but Timer won't update while the screen in being tapped.  I put a background and a text field into a VStack and checked for taps using .onTapGesture, but every time a tap is received it pauses the timer.  Is there a way to run both of them at the same time?

```
var body: some View{
       ZStack{
           Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
           Text(Nstring)
               .font(.system(size: 100))
               .fontWeight(.bold)
           CountdownView()
       }
       .onTapGesture {
           if number == 0{
               active = true
           }
           if active{
               number += 1
               Nstring = String(number)
               print(Nstring)
           }
```

```
struct CountdownView: View {
   @State var TimeRemaining = 30
   
   let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
       .autoconnect()
   
   var body: some View {
       HStack{
           VStack(alignment: .leading){
               Text(String(TimeRemaining))
                   .font(.title)
                   .onReceive(timer){_ in
                       if TimeRemaining != 0 && active{
                           TimeRemaining -= 1
                       }else{
                           active = false
                       }
                   }
               Spacer()
           Spacer()
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? What you've included won't compile

Answer (score 0):

to make the timer count down when you tap on the screen, use the following example code that
uses a binding and a modified `CountdownView` call:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var active: Bool = false  // <--- here
    @State var number: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
            Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("\(number)")
                .font(.system(size: 50))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            CountdownView(active: $active) // <--- here
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            if number == 0 {
                active = true
            }
            if active {
                number += 1
                print("---> number: \(number)")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CountdownView: View {
    @Binding var active: Bool // <--- here
    @State var timeRemaining = 30
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                Text(String(timeRemaining))
                    .font(.title)
                    .onReceive(timer) {_ in
                        if timeRemaining != 0 && active {
                            timeRemaining -= 1
                        } else {
                            active = false
                        }
                    }
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```